# Como atualizar o idioma de uma aplicação JavaFX em tempo de execução

Tags: java, javafx, i18n, locale

Tenho um combobox que contém os idiomas, ao selecionar ele armazena e eu gostaria de já aplicar a atualização do idioma.

Porém queria fazer isso de forma dinâmica. O problema é que eu não sei como fazer para trocar o idioma.

Esse método é chamando quando a opção do combo é selecionada

```
 languages.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Locale>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Locale> observable, Locale oldValue, Locale newValue) {
                LanguageEnum le = CommonService.fromLocale(newValue);
                try {
                    CommonService.setLanguage(le);
                    refreshRender(CommonService.getBundle());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Nesse médoto eu iria renderizar as telas abertas com o idioma selecionado, a intenção era ver qual scene estivesse visível, e alterar o idioma delas, porém eu precisaria saber o fxml que foi carregado para dar o load novamente.

Não sei se é dessa forma, e não sei concluir, pois não consegui achar um método para recuperar a URL da instância de scene que foi usada, não sei se essa é a melhor forma, o objetivo mesmo é ao alterar o idioma com base no idioma selecionado no combo e já aplicar a tradução na tela. Comecei a estudar JavaFX na semana passada então estou bem perdido.

```
   private void refreshRender(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        ObservableList<Stage> stages = StageHelper.getStages();
        for (Stage s : stages) {
            if (!s.isShowing()) {
                continue;
            }
            Scene scene = s.getScene();
            Parent root = scene.getRoot();
    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("xxxx.fxml"), bundle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esse tópico do SOen pode resolver sua dúvida: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/5434/internationalization-in-javafx#t=20170813200741721983

Comment: É uma solução, só que se entendi certo, nesse caso não usará mais o fxml passara a criar os elementos direto via código usando um factory